# Keras Error when Concatenating layers in functional mode

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm attempting to concatenate two layers. According to the documentation, the following should be correct.

```
import tensorflow.keras as K

input = K.Input(shape=(self.state_dimensions(),))
shared_features = K.layers.Dense(10,activation='tanh')
x = K.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh')(input)
a = shared_features(x[0:10])
b = shared_features(x[10:20])
output = K.layers.Concatenate()([a,b])
actor_model = K.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

However, in the last line, this error appears:

```
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("concatenate/concat:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensors `a` and `b` contain operations outside layers. All operations must be inside keras layers.

```
a = K.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:10])(x)
b = K.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[10:20])(x)

a = shared_features(a)
b = shared_features(b)
```

You will have problems as you're splitting the tensor in the batch size dimension. `K.layers.Concatenate()` doesn't work on the batch dimension. You will end up with a different number of samples at the end.

You probably want `x[:,0:10]` and `x[:,10:20]`